# jQuery DataTables Scroller Ajax not being called the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using DataTables jQuery plugin. I am having problem using the [Scroller plugin](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/). It doesn't load more data when the scrolling reaches the end of the container.

**Init in jQuery:**

```
 $("#data-table").dataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "paging": false,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "searching": false,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ordering": false,
    "ajax": {
        "url": CONST_WEB_SERVICE_URL + "GetData",
        "type": "POST"

    },
    "scroller": {
        "loadingIndicator": true,
        "trace": true
    },

    "deferRender": true,
    "dom": "lfrtipS",
    "scrollY": "400px"
   });
```

**My .NET webservice** returns this **JSON data** when DataTables first read it:

```
{
"draw": 1,
"data": [{
    "id": 1.0,
    "name": "88354b7e-c150-4985-b596-113fb3f9f591",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 1
}, {
    "id": 2.0,
    "name": "82f5243d-b68c-4306-a83b-7c5178661bab",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 2
}, {
    "id": 3.0,
    "name": "591c23cb-2ad6-472f-b347-96411bd7ca13",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 3
}, {
    "id": 4.0,
    "name": "cd7eed2e-f175-40c6-86ef-1ef26fdffe62",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 4
}, {
    "id": 5.0,
    "name": "46717542-a68a-48f9-92c7-21fbe94bbee6",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 5
}, {
    "id": 6.0,
    "name": "d73561ac-5885-4fc3-b9ed-2c672298c5e6",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 6
}, {
    "id": 7.0,
    "name": "6c18c250-c8e2-4e66-bb63-d13112cbbb4d",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 7
}, {
    "id": 8.0,
    "name": "3fefb6f7-a35b-44fe-b1be-7dc6cfe59f69",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 8
}, {
    "id": 9.0,
    "name": "7ba7d370-1250-4349-8228-4997b1c9d309",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 9
}, {
    "id": 10.0,
    "name": "56c15c4b-7617-4519-bfbe-aa82d78fd352",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 10
}, {
    "id": 11.0,
    "name": "7c2f49dc-9dad-4521-8a08-707ec60da31f",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 11
}, {
    "id": 12.0,
    "name": "2ca7d4dd-d1df-47dd-8001-e32e0fad0105",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 12
}, {
    "id": 13.0,
    "name": "7ccd94f1-63d7-4d39-8c75-940a3c687b52",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 13
}, {
    "id": 14.0,
    "name": "b3c24654-d27b-497d-bd75-fb3b1f675262",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 14
}, {
    "id": 15.0,
    "name": "68d28801-87c1-4f19-a96e-55b6a33fe609",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 15
}, {
    "id": 16.0,
    "name": "51c880c5-eb5d-41c2-8c07-960097d0f687",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 16
}, {
    "id": 17.0,
    "name": "518fd582-131e-47a2-ae8d-418650433c24",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 17
}, {
    "id": 18.0,
    "name": "6f9f132c-c70b-4a79-8316-c833003ff615",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 18
}, {
    "id": 19.0,
    "name": "bf189639-2e7a-49b3-86c7-5b6a2210635d",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 19
}, {
    "id": 20.0,
    "name": "035940bc-ab81-488d-9853-cab963841508",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 20
}, {
    "id": 21.0,
    "name": "1cb3b0a2-d03b-4792-b5a7-00cc1aeca33a",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 21
}, {
    "id": 22.0,
    "name": "7934e41d-759f-4903-97df-5f0c15547c43",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 22
}, {
    "id": 23.0,
    "name": "e2fe8827-0c02-49ee-9069-65f3349a2086",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 23
}, {
    "id": 24.0,
    "name": "0822288b-5df3-4aba-82fa-0a302eff5411",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 24
}, {
    "id": 25.0,
    "name": "e2b0f808-d0f7-4a80-bd06-4f34c63dcce6",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 25
}, {
    "id": 26.0,
    "name": "7fe22ed9-7629-4f23-8901-f5d328800c21",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 26
}, {
    "id": 27.0,
    "name": "18364942-bbbb-4c86-a310-5e256337c40d",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 27
}, {
    "id": 28.0,
    "name": "433e904f-bf1c-4375-bbf3-b8f78c337efa",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 28
}, {
    "id": 29.0,
    "name": "e55fe861-87d8-4377-91c7-914da0419fee",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 29
}, {
    "id": 30.0,
    "name": "30be927f-8584-47a5-be66-b4df8b4075e8",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 30
}, {
    "id": 31.0,
    "name": "8baaad43-7d1b-4abb-97c9-a81ba5e37dee",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 31
}, {
    "id": 32.0,
    "name": "00f4014f-cc81-47d4-bd12-af9b8c565b50",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 32
}, {
    "id": 33.0,
    "name": "225b4461-8740-45be-a094-9e747f9a7b07",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 33
}, {
    "id": 34.0,
    "name": "0e178b0f-35ec-40dc-850e-5cf84ff0bfbd",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 34
}, {
    "id": 35.0,
    "name": "e95c0aee-e525-4de0-addc-7b77a73df158",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 35
}, {
    "id": 36.0,
    "name": "0c3a2eab-307b-44fe-bcba-ce299cf734cf",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 36
}, {
    "id": 37.0,
    "name": "b0b0f894-c953-4560-8d6e-d13ce88541fb",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 37
}, {
    "id": 38.0,
    "name": "ebfb8188-fa1c-44e8-af98-ea254de85ab9",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 38
}, {
    "id": 39.0,
    "name": "1e726187-8214-4b44-926b-611e9fcb7f93",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 39
}, {
    "id": 40.0,
    "name": "cf298d6c-3858-4645-9ea5-a628d8335ce9",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 40
}, {
    "id": 41.0,
    "name": "3ce51eda-eff3-490a-94a5-09ae0ef4f6e0",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 41
}, {
    "id": 42.0,
    "name": "c0d5b03a-aecb-4a00-b9c9-b1febd4e6262",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 42
}, {
    "id": 43.0,
    "name": "6434056c-f682-40b3-a5c7-4a1bbfc45a6c",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 43
}, {
    "id": 44.0,
    "name": "b8e3adec-f9c4-424c-a09d-aee6563c251e",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 44
}, {
    "id": 45.0,
    "name": "666cea59-850c-45df-949f-4285d0ee9aa7",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 45
}, {
    "id": 46.0,
    "name": "d570807f-1aa8-44b8-8221-188cb550a743",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 46
}, {
    "id": 47.0,
    "name": "64b2353d-bea4-4fcc-b8cd-5dc5c897ac29",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 47
}, {
    "id": 48.0,
    "name": "c8082be2-92e0-4e26-9c66-0a487ed084a8",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 48
}, {
    "id": 49.0,
    "name": "4e4a1a01-aac0-41c0-934e-4fa1086cb82b",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 49
}, {
    "id": 50.0,
    "name": "b194d213-bdf9-4973-8264-f3a156ab5910",
    "rating": 40.0,
    "votes": 50
}],
"recordsTotal": 5000000,
"recordsFiltered": 5000000
}
```

I generated this results by code for testing.

DataTables reads the recordsTotal and should know that there are more data to be read. **The data is shown in the table correctly** in a 200px container as specified, but when I scroll to the end, it doesn't initiate another ajax call to the server to retrieve more data.

What changes I need to make in order for the Scroller plugin to continuously read data from the server?

I tried with `paging: true` without success. I get no errors in the console.

When I comment out `bLengthChange` and `paging`, the paging works, but scrolling to the bottom doesn't initiate another call to the server to get the second page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some potential problems with your initialization code and data:

- No column data definitions ([columns.data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data)) are available even though you use objects in your JSON response.
- Pagination (`p`) and length changing controls (`l`) should not specified in `dom` parameter if you're not using them.
- Data format is correct but make sure you're returning the same `draw` value given to you in request and the number of records requested in `length` parameter (see [full list of request parameters](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side)).

I believe the correct code should look like:

```
$("#data-table").dataTable({
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ordering": false,
    "searching": false,
    "ajax": {
        "url": CONST_WEB_SERVICE_URL + "GetData",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "scroller": {
        "loadingIndicator": true
    },
    "deferRender": true,
    "dom": "rtiS",
    "scrollY": "400px",
    "columns": [
        {"data": "id"}, 
        {"data": "name"}, 
        {"data": 'rating'}, 
        {"data": 'votes'}
    ]
 });
```

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kutxw864/4/) for an example. I used a different AJAX function just to simulate server-side processing.

Comment: Hi, I am trying it now, Thanks. Please tell me, why I always get -1 in length (return all rows). It there an option to set how many rows to retrieve based on the scroller height and item height?

Comment: This is where it gets interesting. In the JSFiddle example above I experimented with changing the height of the table, that affects the number of records being requested. Maybe your table is hidden when Scroller calculates number of records required. See [fnMeasure](http://datatables.net/docs/Scroller/1.2.0/Scroller.html#fnMeasure) function from Scroller API  that could be used to recalculate number of rows. Please note that the example seems to be for DataTables 1.9.x branch and may need to be updated to use DataTables 1.10.x API.

Comment: My table is not hidden, but the first data isn't in the table and rendered on server side, the Datatables reads the first page. So I assume it has its own  height measurement function that test the height after the first batch of rows are retrieved from the ajax call, am I right?

Comment: I believe Scroller does height measurement when you initialize DataTables library, the height is constrained by `scrollY` parameter. The fact that the data isn't there initially should not matter. I have updated the code at JSFiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/kutxw864/1/) , can you try adding `"paging": true` to your DataTables initialization code and see if that affects the `length` in request.

Comment: Hi, I am using client side processing scroller based and it is working fine if I remove column specific search, else after scrolling to certain position, blank screen is coming and data is not getting loaded.

Comment: @Nitish, start a new question possibly adding a reproducible example and send me a message, I will try to help.